# Netbeans uninstallation error

Tags: exception

When I tried to uninstall netbeans from my system,I get the following error during my uninstallation..

```
An unknown error occured.

Exception:
org.netbeans.installer.utils.exception.UninstallationException:Failed to stop  the default domain.
You can get more details about the issue in the installer log file: C:\Users\Elcot\.nbi\log\20150321190249.log
```

Please suggest me a way to solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide the log file's content also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug caused by installing Glassfish into the Netbeans installation directory. See this bugzilla entry:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=202619

Try to reinstall netbeans and then uninstall, *disabling* the option "delete netbeans installation folder". After this delete the folder manually.

Maybe this should work. I've had similar problems and doing this helped.

Comment: @Matthias: provide me your mail id so that I can mail you my log file